# Android - set activity result on activity closed

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult, onpause, onbackpressed

To start activity for result:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,EVENT_DETAILS_REQUEST);
```

In my DetailsActivity, to set result and extras, that can be used in main activity:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra("isEdited",isEdited);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,resultIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

Finally, in MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @NonNull Intent data)
{
  switch(requestCode)
  {
    ......
    case EVENT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
    boolean isEdited = data.getBooleanExtra("isEdited", false);
    .......
    break;

  }

}
```

This is fine as long as user is using "Back" hardware (or system navbar) button to close DetailsActivity. If user tap "Back" arrow at the top of the activity to close activity, `onBackPressed` won't be called and `onActivityResult` data will be null.

I have tried to use `onPause`, `onStop`, `onFinish` instead of `onBackPressed` to manage it working, but I'm getting `data` for `onActivityResult` always null.

What is correct way to solve my problem?

Comment: Use android:launchMode="singleTop" in menifest file..

Comment: It's already there.

Comment: Please paste your onOptionsItemSelected code.

Comment: It's not there. Should I capture back arrow click in `onOptionsItemSelected`? What id to check?

Comment: See Manoj's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Override this method in your detail activity... and this code

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks. I had no idea where to capture activity back arrow press event.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this to send result in all possible close cases:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.putExtra("isEdited", isEdited);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    super.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your DetailsActivity

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
       Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra("isEdited",isEdited);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,resultIntent);
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is automatically called when hardware backpressed ..

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

             //your code here   

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```